# Is there an API function i can use to comment on an album on Google Photos

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-photos-api

So basically i have a shared album on Google Photos and i want to know if there's an API function which will let me provide comments on the album, since i was searching and the closest thing was adding enrichments to the album which was close but not exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I think that in the current stage, there are no methods in Photo API for adding the comment to the album. But in order to correctly understand about `the closest thing was adding enrichments to the album which was close`, can you show the sample image?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.